# Laravel - CSRF protection not working

Tags: php, laravel, filter, controller

So, I have a RESTful controller, meaning that I have to define the CSRF filter usage in the controller. I've looked up how it works and I'm pretty sure what I have should be working. Sadly, even when I remove the token from the form, it still submits just fine and doesn't error. Here's the constructor of my controller:

```
$this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('only' => 'post'));

$teams = Team::all();
$streamers = Streamer::all();

View::share('teams', $teams);
View::share('streamers', $streamers);
```

In my form I simply use *{{ Form::token() }}* and even if I have that removed it still works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
$this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('only' => 'post'));
```

to this

```
$this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on' => 'post'));
```

**Explaination**

`only` or `except` is for controller methods (index, show, update, ...) and `on` is for HTTP methods (post, get, put, delete)

**EDIT**

If it is still not working, then paste your CSRF filter, if you edited it. Also make sure you are on the right route. If you defined your beforeFilter in BaseController, make sure your other controllers include `parent::__construct()` in the controller, if present.

Comment: Still submits just fine without the token.

Comment: Apparently it default to adding a token to any form so it was stil submitting a valid token.